# Laravel's Auth::attempt() returns true but Auth::check() returns false

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

As the title says, Laravel's function `Auth::attempt()` returns `true` in the following code section (with unimportant parts deleted):

```
public function doLogin()
{
    $validator = [..]

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        [..]
    } else {
        $userdata = array(
            'username'  => Input::get('username'),
            'password'  => Input::get('password')
        );

        if (Auth::attempt($userdata, true)) {
            return Redirect::to('/');
        } else {        
            return Redirect::to('login');
        }
    }
}
```

But when we are redirected, we try to check if an user is really logged in with `Auth::check()`, and it returns `false` somehow.

We have tried every possible solution on Google and did not succeed with any of it. For example we added a `remember_token` but it did not change anything, though it proved us that the `Auth::attempt()` does something because the `remember_token` is set in the database.

As a last resort, we even tried to print something in the `Auth::attempt()` method of Laravel in `./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php` but we did not see anything of that, not even with `print_r`. We tried to find other attempt-functions in the complete codebase but none is found.

It could be that something about changing `User` to an translated form of it makes it broken, but then the function `Auth::attempt()` should also be broken, probably.

It seems that something really magical happens but we have no idea what or how. Does anybody else have an idea?

Comment: In `app/config/auth.php` which driver do you have set?  And in `app/config/session.php` which driver is set there?

Comment: @user3158900: eloquent and file respectively.

Comment: You could have some permissions on the file which is making it misbehave.  Try modifying the permissions of the `app/storage/sessions` directory.  If that doesn't work, see if it will work by using a different session driver.

Comment: We are working locally so the permissions shouldn't be a problem afaik. Using a different session driver doesn't help, we tried cookie and see that it makes the correct cookie but still the same problem.

Comment: Do sessions in general work? `Session::put('foo', 'bar')` and in another request `Session::get('foo')`

Comment: @lukasgeiter: yes. I get `string(3) "bar"` back.

Comment: Hmm. So the session isn't the problem. Maybe the `remember` option is messing something up here. Have you tried `Auth::attempt($userdata)`?

Comment: Do you have some files in `app/storage/sessions` ?

Comment: @Maximilian Prepl: yes, there are. One file as one would expect when trying to login with one account. If you want to see the contents, please say.

Comment: @lukasgeiter: we tried that beforehand and again just now, but also no success, with and without statically deleting the `remember_token` from the database for the corresponding account.

Comment: did you have modified `cookie` or `domain` var in `session.php`?

Comment: @MaximilianPrepl: they are `laravel_session` and `null` respectively, and AFAIK we didn't change them.

Comment: is there some messages in laravel.log under `app/storage/logs`?

Comment: I had a similar problem that had me scratching my head for a while a few months back.  It turned out that i replaced the default `User` model.  Does your `User` model include all of the traits and namespaces as the [default User model](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/models/User.php) in the Laravel distribution?

Comment: @Renzeee I had similar problem  today.

Have you define primary key in Model?.

because i have not define primary key in `User` model and after defining primary key everything works fine for me. So try this. May be this would help you.

Comment: @c-griffin The problem was indeed that we changed the User model.

Answer (score 7):

By default, Laravel assumes that each table has a primary key called id.

Possible solution is to do this in your model:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id'; //Or what ever id name do you have.
```

This error may occur if you are trying to use laravel-mongodb with custom increment and unique generated id rather than the default _id from MongoDB. The solution in this case is not to name your custom id like this 'id' because it will make Laravel confused. However, name it anything else.

Comment: I am facing same problem, I am using `laravel-mongodb`. I tried the solutions given in the comments but no success. Is there any other solution for it?

Comment: thank you sooooo much for saving me a lot of time, would've taken me ages to figure this one out

Comment: My GOD !!!!! I WANT TO PERSONALLY THANK YOU .... AFTER SIX  HOURS .. YOU FIXED MY ISSUE . THANKS A LOT !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

for those who still have this problem, if your primary key doesnt follow autoIncrement, you should add this following code to your User model:

```
public $incrementing=false;
```

and if you have changed your primary column name, add this:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'vid'; //changed to vid
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar error, at login then redirest, `Auth::user() returned null`.

I discovered the culprit is the data type of `created_at, updated_at which is string`. The solution is to convert the `string` data type to `mongoDB date`

In other cases I suggest checking your user table, there may be a mistake somewhere